# How to turn OFF Translucent Selection Rectangle in the Windows Explorer (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, selection, performance-tuning

[image: The Bad]

[image: The Good]

This is Windows 7.
In **System properties** -> **Performance options** -> **Adjust for best performance**

It makes what I want only for the **Desktop** if I go into folder and try to select the files the selection rectangle is like in the first image.

How to make it everywhere?

Comment: this is in windows 7?  It uses the dotted selection in my 3rd party file manager, so it must be the explorer shell itself ?, and the new interface for it.  It even uses that in the "classic" themes.

Comment: I have always had `show translucent selection rectangle` off, and I just noticed this! Confirmed.

Comment: @iglvzx it seems that it is normal behaviour for the Windows 7. According to http://malektips.com/windows-7-desktop-translucent-selection-rectangle.html and other sources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can find out, show translucent selection rectangle off used to work in Vista for both the desktop and Windows Explorer.

However, since Windows 7 the Windows Explorer ignores this setting and always uses the filled selection rectangle, no matter its setting. This is no doubt a new bug introduced in Windows 7.

Sorry to be negative, but in my opinion the most one can do is file a bug report with Microsoft as regarding this issue.

Unfortunately, there's no submit a bug report option directly. The way one does it is to call Microsoft Support and open a support request (can also be done online). If they can reproduce your issue and verify that it's actually a bug they will file a bug report.

[**EDIT**]

I found a way of forcing Explorer to honor the Translucent Selection Rectangle setting that is found in the registry in the key :
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
You should set the value of `ListviewAlphaSelect`
to zero (0) to disable the Translucent Selection Rectangle.

Unfortunately this change is ignored by the list-view control of Windows 7 (DirectUIHWND).
One must therefore force Windows 7 to use the old list-view control from Windows Vista.

The following article contains a registry hack which (incidentally) will accomplish this:
[How to Disable Full Row Select in Explorer in Windows 7](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-full-row-select-explorer-windows-7/).

It links to a [zip file](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/h1-10/w7-fullrowsel.zip) that contains two .reg files : One effects the change and the other undoes it. I tried it inside a vanilla virtual machine and it worked for me.

I would still suggest to create a system restore point before using this hack.

Comment: yes that's fun. Windows 7 was released 2.5 years ago. Still hope to fix this. Even thinking about using custom Windows Explorer

Comment: One can still hope for Windows 8 ;) . However, Microsoft has a history of not caring about small bugs.

Comment: Semi official statement was that this is a bug. And since Windows 7 is in maintenance mode (it only accepts security/crash patches) so possibly this issue will never be fixed for Windows 7. WIll wait until bounty ends and will accept this answer

Comment: Read my edit above.

Comment: It is not working for certain folders though like User's "Images". But this is awesome! I could give even more of my reputation

Comment: No need - 300 is enough. Enjoy.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you Thank you.  I was wondering if it was somehow related to full row select, because on the 3rd party stuff i have FRS off for sure.

Comment: The 3rd party product might still be using the old Vista list-view activex control.